# Design for table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table:

```
TABLE
(
A int, 
B int, 
..., 
H int, 
DataValue float
);
```

All of my queries do aggregate operations, with A and some other columns (several combinations) in the WHERE clause (A is always in).

What type of table design (partition/not; PK(Identity) OR PK(A, B, ..., H); rowStore/columnStore indexes) should I apply?

Answer (score 0):

Partition is Enterprise Edition only, hence quite expensive.
It makes large tables (>1TB) easier to work with, but it my book, it does not necessarily make queries run faster.

You need to describe the contents on the A column a bit better, to determine if the column should be part of the Primary Key, and also if it is always WHERE A=42 or WHERE A in (1,2,3,42)

IMHO the Column A needs to be NOT NULL if you want it as primary key.

Kimberly Tripp has some good blog posts on selecting the Clustered Key: [for instance this one.](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/)

Comment: Column A has ~10 distinct values and it's always "WHERE A=8" (or other integer).

Comment: @user2820173; then SQL Server can jump right into the index, if the index has Column A as the first column in the PK. No real savings on Partitioning by Column A. 
We partition by a DateTime column, where each partition is one month wide.